# I don't understand the premotification of the noun コ一ト

Tags: translation, meaning

真冬みたいなふっかふかのコ一ト

Is the coat described above a winter coat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 真冬みたいなふっかふかのコ一ト　
>   Is the coat described above a winter coat?

Yes, you are correct.
[Here](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88&hl=ja&rlz=1T4MEIW_jaJP596JP596&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6pZ22msXUAhXGkpQKHY0ZCHcQ_AUIBigB&biw=1154&bih=525#hl=ja&tbm=isch&q=%E5%86%AC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88&spf=1497713667947) is your coat.
**ふっかふかの** コート is **ふかふかの** コート a ***fluffy*** coat.